# solr sunspot exact search for words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I have an archive of ~50 M Tweets. I want to see if other users mention each other. There are problems though: There is an account called facebook (www.twitter.com/facebook). I want to search for those tweets that mention this account and do not simply say facebook.

So my syntax using sunspot is:

```
search = FeedEntry.search do        
  without(:person_id,person.id) # No self referencing
  fulltext "@#{person.username}" #Find those Feeds that mention this person
  paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 1000000 #Make sure we dont paginate 
end
```

Solr seems to neglect the @ sign totally and even when  search putting the username in "" or '' it doesnt matter.

```
search = FeedEntry.search{fulltext "facebook -RT"}
=> <Sunspot::Search:{:start=>0, :defType=>"dismax", :fq=>["type:FeedEntry"], :rows=>30, :q=>"facebook -RT", :fl=>"* score", :qf=>"retweeters_text text_text"}>
>> search.total
=> 299525
```

What can I do? I have to go through those results and use ruby "include? "@facebook" to sort out the false positives which is time consuming.

I have the suspicion that it has to do with the tokenizer factories I am using:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory

My config in the schema.xml is:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I think changing the StandardTokenizerFactory to WhitespaceTokenizerFactory would help in my case. Btw. is there a way to see which tokens these factories produced on my corpus?

My final question is do I need a re-indexing after changing the tokenizer? My assumption is yes.

Cheers
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

If you can parse hash tags, re-tweets, @name etc as you index these tweets and use separate fields in solr,  then you will have more powerful search (IMHO).

Changing to whitespace tokenizer should help as you noted, and you will need to reindex. You will need to use the same tokenizer,analyzer during search as well.

Comment: You are right I might create proper db fields for them and store them as additional data for the tweet. It seems that what Twitter is also doing, since they can report the "entities" mentioned by the tweets also. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The `StandardTokenizerFactory` throws out punctuation, with the exception of a period not followed by whitespace. In particular, it throws out "@", so your @name search is doomed (as would be searches for complete email addresses. While `ClassicTokenizerFactory` preserves email addresses, I believe it still throws out the "@" from @name.

The `WhitespaceTokenizerFactory` will preserve @name, but it will treat it differently if it is followed by a comma ( `@name` is not the same as `@name,` ) so it may still not be the right thing for you. You might end up wanting to use the `PatternTokenizerFactory` where you specify exactly how you want to parse via regular expressions.